# Update Association with JSON Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Using a JSON API I want to update `company.name`. A `user` belongs_to a `company`. What could we do to make sure that a user shouldn't update a company that they aren't part of? Note `user` may not have a company

I looked into `validates_associated` but I'm not sure how it would be implemented. Note, we pass a company object from the front end.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class CompanyController < ApplicationController
  def update
    if @current_user.company.update_attributes(params[:company])
      render updated and return
    else
      render not_found and return
    end
  end
  def company_params
    params.require(:company).permit(:name)
  end
end

describe "#update" do
  it " company name" do
    @company.name = "new_name"
    put :update, :token_id => "fake_token_id", :id => @company.id, :company => {:name => @company.name}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your `update` action:

```
def update
  company = Company.find(params[:id])
  if !@current_user.company.nil? and company == @current_user.company
    if @current_user.company.update_attributes(params[:company])
      render updated and return
    else
      render fail_to_update and return
    end
  else
    render not_found and return
  end
end
```

Comment: This should raise a `DoubleRenderError` exception.

Comment: @Зелёный Can you explain how could that happen?

Comment: @Yang, I forgot to add "and return" in my sample code to prevent double render. My bad, "render fail_to_update and return"

Comment: Can you please add "and return after your render and then I can accept the answer"

Comment: Also I get a "ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError" on the update_attributes command. Please see the edited code

Comment: Please check if you have something like `attr_accessible :name` in your `Company` model

Comment: Stupid mistake.. have to call @current_user.company.update_attributes(company_params) in rails 4

Answer (score 3):

Since you are calling update_attributes on the @current_user.company, that company will always belong to the @current_user and it will be the only one which gets updated.

Now if for any reason you submit the company update params to your #update action and the user does not have a company you could add:

```
def update
  if @current_user.company && @current_user.company.update_attributes(params[:company])
    render updated
  else
    render not_found
  end
end
```

Comment: If you look into the test code, there is a `param[:id]` in that API request. I think checking if it matches the `current_user`'s company will make the logic solid.

Comment: Since the action is intended to update the @current_user's company that params[:id] is obsolete

Comment: We have to keep in mind that your solution updates the current_users company regardless of param[:id]. So passing another company param[:id], will still update the current_user.company attributes. In REST API I would think that the request should fail instead.